# Adicionar protetor de links automaticamente em links de servidores

Tags: php, javascript

Ola gostaria de saber como posso usar JavaScript ou PHP para colocar essa url  `http://anunciad.com.br?AuID=16958&Aurl=` antes dos endereços dos servidores de download automaticamente eu uso esses servidores **SkyDrive, Clouddrive, Pcloud, Bitcasa, Meocloud, LolaBits, Google, Clouddriver** eu usava o **Adfly** ele possui um script em JavaScript que adiciona o endereço automaticamente no inicio destas URLs o endereço do protetor. 
Com tudo esse novo protetor não dispoem essa especie de scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com **JavaScript** nativo da seguinte forma:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    var urlProtegida = "http://anunciad.com.br?AuID=16958&Aurl=" + link.href;

    link.href = urlProtegida;
}
```

Ou com **jQuery**:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var urlProtegida = "http://anunciad.com.br?AuID=16958&Aurl=" + $(this).attr("href");

    $(this).attr("href", urlProtegida);
});
```

Com **jQuery** é possível ainda *fazer um filtro para alterar apenas os links cuja URL contenha do domínio de algum dos servidores mencionados* na sua pergunta.

```
// Lista de bases de URLs dos servidores.
var urlsBases = ["meocloud.pt", "mega.co.nz", "outro.servidor.com"];

for (var i = 0; i < urlsBases.length; i++) {
    var serverUrlBase = urlsBases[i];

    // OBS: é necessário colocar entre aspas simples a url no filtro do jQuery por atributo.
    $("a[href*='" + serverUrlBase + "']").each(function() {
        var urlProtegida = "http://anunciad.com.br?AuID=16958&Aurl=" + $(this).attr("href");

        $(this).attr("href", urlProtegida);
    });
}
```

Comment: No caso ambas pegam qualquer item com http:// e poem isso automaticamente certo ?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo. Caso você precise pegar apenas links específicos eu posso atualizar a resposta para fazer essa filtragem e assim pegar apenas os links que você precisa proteger.

Comment: Se puder fazer isso agradeço imensamente pois e exatamente disso que preciso no caso que de pra eu por os hosts que eu quiser mais de um no caso uma listagem.

Comment: No caso para as urls do https://meocloud.pt/, http://mega.co.nz etc.

Comment: @Rodrigo fiz a alteração. Aí você na sua lista de URL bases as demais urls dos servidores que precisar proteger.

Comment: Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Acho que fiz algo errado coloquei desta forma <script src="protetor.js"></script> e criei um arquivo .js e coloquei esse código de jquery mais não colocou a url link não sei o que fiz de errado. Coloquei ele antes do </head>

Comment: Você importou o jQuery? Se possível, por favor crie um fiddle de seu código para que eu analise o que pode estar faltando. Pra criar o fiidle você acesa o site http://www.jsfiddle.net coloca seu código lá e me passa o link.

Comment: Aqui o link http://jsfiddle.net/bajw0hch/

Comment: Encontrei o erro, @Rodrigo. Faltou eu colocar aspas simples cercando a URL no filtro por atributo do jQuery em $("a[href*='" + serverUrlBase + "']"). Agora já atualizei a resposta, e o correto é **$("a[href*='" + serverUrlBase + "']")** (repare que adicionei aspas simples após o = e antes do ]). Tente assim agora que dará certo.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não esta funcionando.

Comment: @Rodrigo No meu fiddle está funcionando ok. https://jsfiddle.net/UlyssesAlves/23bqqf0j/3/ Você está executando o código no $(document).ready() ? Às vezes é isso. Você apenas criou a função mas não chamou ela, e por isso ela não está fazendo nada. Dá uma olhada no meu fiddle por favor (https://jsfiddle.net/UlyssesAlves/23bqqf0j/3/). Eu primeiro criei a função e depois chamei ela no $(document).ready e funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
$urlBase = 'http://anunciad.com.br?AuID=16958&Aurl=';

$urlTotal = $urlBase . 'www.skydrive.com/arquivo1.mp3';
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda mais necessito realmente do método  postado  pelo Ulysses de forma que coloque automaticamente no caso em URLs especificas o protetor.

Comment: Foi mal eu só havia desmarcado a pergunta como aceita mais des marquei a pois ter visto a resposta acima que era o que eu queria. E sei que o método também e aplicável mais só iria servir para mim caso eu já tivesse conteúdo e como eu uso WordPress para mim em JavaScript e melhor.